# Common TVF in SQL Server to get results from different schema

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I have been using SQL Server for the past month and I need a suggestion from SQL Server folks to help me on this use case.

The tables below are just to explain about the idea that I am looking for.

I have tables in different schema like this:

```
MyDb.dbo.Festivals
MyDb.India.Festivals
MyDb.China.Festivals
MyDb.USA.Festivals
```

I am writing a table value function without any schema prefixed in it like

```
CREATE FUNCTION getFestivals()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
       (SELECT * FROM festivals)
```

As I haven't applied any schema, it defaults to `dbo` and creates the TVF as `dbo.getFestivals()`. Now I have created synonyms for all other schemas

```
CREATE SYNONYM India.getFestivals FOR dbo.getFestivals; 
CREATE SYNONYM USA.getFestivals FOR dbo.getFestivals;
```

I tried to query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyDb.India.getFestivals()
```

and it returns the festivals from `dbo.festivals` and not `india.festivals`.

I understand that though the synonyms, we've created it just executes the select query in the `dbo` schema context and not in `india` schema context.

I want suggestions on how to have a common table value function that will query based on the schema prefixed, i.e. `MyDB.India.getFestivals()` should get festivals from India and `MyDB.USA.getFestivals()` should return festivals from USA.

**Question**

1. Is there a way I can have a table value function that can query based on the schema context.
2. the only possible way I can think of is to create the same TableValue function in all schemas

Caveats

1. I have to stick to table value function only and the above use case is a sample scenario to explain my problem

Comment: Have you tried dynamic SQL?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, Inside table value we cannot use dynamic value functions. I dont want to use multiline table value function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that though the synonyms, we've created it just executes
>   the select query in the dbo schema context and not in india schema
>   context.

You should always schema qualify objects in your queries, since you did not do it, SQL Server first looks for `festivals` in the same schema where the procedure resides, if it's not found then `dbo` schema is checked, if it's not found even in `dbo`, the error is raised.

In your case procedure resides in `dbo` schema so only `dbo` schema is checked in order to find `festivals`.

It may be wrong design if many "similar" tables are created instead of one table, can you merge them all into one table adding country_id to distinguish the country?

If not, can you at least add this field to every table? If it's so, just add the field for the country in every table, add check constraint on this field to reflect the only country that is stored in every table an then use `partitioned view` in your function.

`Partitioned view` is a view composed of `union all` of some tables with the same structure, each of which has check constraint on the same column that defines the values this column is restricted to. When you use this view with the filter on country column, all the tables except for the correct one will be eliminated from execution plan thanks to `check constraint` defined on this column.

So you can change your function to accept the only parameter that is country and it will read only one table corresponding to parameter passed.

More on partitioned views here: [Using Partitioned Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: thankyou very much, I never knew of partitioned views. This is the best solution that ll cater my demands since this invovles lot of history table, I dont have the liberty of changing the schema, thankx again for help